# OBSOLETE - Stack Favorites: A basic organizer of your Stack Overflow favorites

Tags: app, obsolete, website, stackoverflow, favorite

> ## App no longer available for use and not in development.

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

This basic website allows users to organize their Stack Overflow favorites by tags, or search through favorites by keywords.

#### License

No specific license — free for any use.

#### Platform

Currently tested for compatibility on the latest Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer.

### Code

jQuery and another StackApp called StackUnderflow.js

Comment: Is this app actually hosted anywhere, or do we have to host it individually?

Comment: Something like this is desperately needed. Thank you. I will keep playing with the app, but one feature that would make this an indispensable tool is if I could organize multiple stack accounts at once. For example, I have favorites with the `mysql` tag across at least 3 or 4 accounts - If I could organize them in one page it would drastically improve workflow when referencing my stack favorites.

Comment: Hi @Anton, so happy this is still up after all these years.  It's still a better way to browse favorites -- even though SO now supports tag searching within your fav's now -- since you have that tab where you can *browse* by tag.  Curious how you sort those tags?  Would be nice to sort by number of posts saved.  I don't do a lot of web programming - how hard would it be to alter that sort order?  Thanks again for building and maintaining this!

Comment: Can you add a feature to search ALL SO sites?

Comment: @Anton Good job. Now it's not really used anymore, since we can use `infavorites:mine`. However, we cannot search for upvoted questions (on all SE sites), so   this would be a welcoming add-on (to include upvoted questions and allow searching on all SE sites).

Answer (score 4):

Seems to work quite well. I do have a couple of suggestions:

1. On the "organized into Tags" page, it is necessary to click on the tiny "+" sign to drop down the questions for the particular tag. Perhaps it could be extended to the entire row?
2. Also, when a search term is not found, there is no visual feedback saying "search term was not found" or something similar to indicate that the search did indeed complete but returned nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I updated the site with your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is so freakin' AWESOME  - thanks for building this!  As far as I know this is the ONLY way to search your favorites now.  A couple quick questions/suggestions:

1. Any idea why it doesn't work in Firefox (I'm on v14). (works great in Chrome)
2. Would you consider adding tag search like in the S.O. search engine (surrounded by brackets like [python])?  The tag browse feature you have is cool but sometimes I want to search for a combination of tags and terms.  Actually, if you REALLY wanted to maximize utility, since I don't always remember what tags are on my favorites, how about doing this:  when you currently list the pages under the tag after I click on it, list the other tags that are also included ON JUST THOSE PAGES.  Then I could browse easily for any combination of tags I desire - just like using "related tags" on S.O.  (I realize that would be hard to build though because you would have to nest it to an arbitrary length, so I would just love to have tags in search and maybe just a tag cloud or list of all the tags in my favorites so I don't have to guess at names).

But anyway, these are just wish lists.  I'm really really happy to just have a way to SEARCH!  thanks again!