# SEAPI - A lightweight Python wrapper for the Stack Exchange API

Tags: library, api-v2, python

#### About

A lightweight Python wrapper for [the Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) v2.1.
Built with [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/).

Why yet another SE API Python wrapper? (I'm aware of [Stack.PY - A Python Module for Accessing the Stack Exchange 2.1 API](https://stackapps.com/questions/3417/stack-py-a-python-module-for-accessing-the-stack-exchange-2-1-api) and [Py-StackExchange: An API wrapper for Python](https://stackapps.com/questions/198/py-stackexchange-an-api-wrapper-for-python).)

For me there were two key things:

- make commands as straightforward as possible,
- make easy to harvest a lot of pages.

First, because I wanted to use commands directly from [the documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs), e.g.:

```
se = SEAPI.SEAPI()
se.fetch("users/{ids}/comments/{toid}", ids=[29407, 23354], toid=22656,
          sort="creation", order="desc", site="stackoverflow")
```

Second arose from practical reason - I wanted to plot [Map of all SE sites (except the 3 biggest)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/157976/map-of-all-se-sites-except-the-3-biggest), see also [Tag Graph Map of Stack Exchange wiki at GitHub](https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange/wiki), using e.g.:

```
se.fetch("users", site="cogsci")
```

to easily get `user_id`, `account_id` and `reputation`.

#### License

An open license [CC BY 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/).
No warranty etc.

#### Download

From GitHub: https://github.com/stared/se-api-py.

Do you want to raise an issue or contribute? Great!

#### Contact

`pmigdal@gmail.com`

#### General philosophy of usage

- se.fetch[_one](command, **parameters)
- parameters as in the documentation
- in the command, "{something}" and "{somethings}" are treated as placeholders for an int/str or a list of int/str, respectively

#### Examples

```
import SEAPI
se = SEAPI.SEAPI()

some_users = se.fetch_one("users/{ids}", ids=[1,3,7,9,13], site="stackoverflow") 

all_user = se.fetch("users", site="academia")
```

Now, `some_users` and `all_user` are lists with the respective response from each query.

Alternatively, you can initialize SEAPI with default options, typically - site name, e.g.

```
so = SEAPI.SEAPI(site="stackoverflow")

some_questions = so.fetch("questions", page_limit=10)
# except for very small sites, you want to set page limit

some_sorted_posts = so.fetch_one("posts", order="desc", sort="votes")
# for sorting sometimes asking for more that one results in "throttle violation"
```

If you want to diagnose a problem, or avoid it:

```
so.last_call
# lookup at the last command sent

so.last_status
# check the last response status

slow_food = so.fetch("tags", min_delay=0.5)
# or set delay (by default it's 0.05)
```

#### Feedback

I'm a beginner, so all remarks with respect to the code quality, good practices, etc are welcome!

Comment: This seems by and large abandoned. Maybe see instead https://stackapps.com/questions/6841/stackapi-another-python-wrapper

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: I would like to retrieve all the related tags of a particular tag using your package, much like what is accomplished [here](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-tags#tags=pointers&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Step 2: I would like to find the intersection between two lists of related tags.

**RELATED**: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19898666/307454

Comment: `x = so.fetch("/tags/{tag}/related", tag=tag1)`, `y = so.fetch("/tags/{tag}/related", tag=tag2)` and the rest is Python (e.g. get tag names and make set intersection, if it is what you have in mind).

Comment: SEAPI is clean, efficient and a breath of fresh air compared to the other StackApps I've struggled with all night! It would be great if it incorporated authentication using [requests_oauthlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib). Is that already in the works?

Comment: SEAPI is not under active development. But if you want some changes, why not forking the repository - I would be happy to accept some pull requests. :)

Comment: Sorry, I am adding this here, but TimStone already deleted the other answer. The API seems to work okay for StackFavorites - http://stackapps.com/q/2438/12360. `so.fetch("/users/{ids}/favorites",ids = [id], order="desc", sort="added", page=1)` is what I am using, but it did not work.

Comment: I did click on the http://api.stackexchange.com/ you posted and it didn't respond to order parameter. As the SEAPI has no ambition beyond translating Pythonic queries to StackExchange API, there is little I can do. Maybe the other app uses a different query or takes all favourites (I guess, rarely more than a few thousands) and performs the sorting? I do not know.

Comment: You are right, that's what I probably need to do. THanks,